# Can't download data from Yahoo Finance using Quantmod in R

Tags: r, yahoo, quantmod, yahoo-finance, r-package

I'm trying to download data from Yahoo using this code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("WOW", auto.assign=F)
```

This has worked for me in the past in every occasion except now, 5 days before my group assignment is due.

Except now I receive this error:

```
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : cannot download all files
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  URL 'https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?
s=WOW&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=4&e=17&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=WOW&x=.csv': status was 
'502 Bad Gateway'
```

Comment: That's a current issue with the Yahoo server. You'll just have to wait until they fix it, or use another data source.

Comment: @neilws Ah true, I can still download historical data from the website?  Are you having similar issues with downloading data?

Comment: I'm currently seeing an error page at https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com

Comment: Yeah right, so that is different from https://au.finance.yahoo.com/ where I was looking. Thank you!

Comment: You could download a CSV from here: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WOW.AX/history?p=WOW.AX

Comment: Yeah that's true, except it's so much effort to import that into R and then use the data with quantmod. I think I'll just wait for it to come back online.

Comment: Even with workarounds this free data source from Yahoo is becoming increasingly unreliable.
It now seems that the "Adj Close" column of downloaded data is in fact not adjusted.
I wonder if there are moderately price historical data sources that have an API that could be called from R?

Answer (score 11):

The price history csv URL's appear to have changed

Old
https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=2&b=17&c=2017&d=3&e=17&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv

New:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1492438581&period2=1495030581&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=XXXXXXX

The new version appends a "crumb" field which appears to reflect cookie information in the user's browser.  It seems they are intentionally blocking automated downloads of price histories and forcing queries to provide information to validate cookies in a web browser

Comment: Cool, so how can I download data from the new url?

Answer (score 9):

The fix is detailed at https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/157

Essentialy

```
remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref="157_yahoo_502")
# or
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref="157_yahoo_502")
```

Comment: Thanks! Except I'm still not able to get it to work.  I get an error when I try and run the code

    Error: Command failed (1)

I'm very new to programming with R.  This is my code so far:

    library(quantmod)
    library(curl)

    remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")
    # or
    devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")

    getSymbols("WOW", auto.assign = F)

Comment: All good I fixed it! For anyone in the future reading this I had to use my Windows PC and install Devtools.  Then just run those lines and it'll start working.

Answer (score 3):

Version 0.4-9 of quantmod fixes this issue, and is now available on [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=quantmod).

Answer (score 2):

I've always wondered why Yahoo was so nice as to provide data downloads and how screwed I would be if they stopped doing it. Fortunately, help is on the way courtesy Joshua Ulrich.

Superfluous as it now may be, I coded a fix that shows one approach to get around the download problem.

```
library(xts)
getSymbols.yahoo.fix <- function (symbol, 
                                  from       = "2007-01-01", 
                                  to         = Sys.Date(), 
                                  period     = c("daily","weekly","monthly"),
                                  envir      = globalenv(),
                                  crumb      = "YourCrumb",
                                  DLdir      = "~/Downloads/") { #1
     # build yahoo query
     query1    <- paste("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/",symbol,"?",sep="")
     fromPosix <- as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(from))
     toPosix   <- as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(to))
     query2    <- paste("period1=", fromPosix, "&period2=", toPosix, sep = "")
     interval  <- switch(period[1], daily = "1d", weekly = "1wk", monthly = "1mo")
     query3    <- paste("&interval=", interval, "&events=history&crumb=", crumb, sep = "")
     yahooURL  <- paste(query1, query2, query3, sep = "")
     #' requires browser to be open
     utils::browseURL("https://www.google.com")
     #' run the query - downloads the security as a csv file
     #' DLdir defaults to download directory in browser preferences
     utils::browseURL(yahooURL)
     #' wait 500 msec for download to complete - mileage may vary
     Sys.sleep(time = 0.5)
     yahooCSV  <- paste(DLdir, symbol, ".csv", sep = "")
     yahooDF   <- utils::read.csv(yahooCSV, header = TRUE)
     #' ------- 
     #' if you get: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
     #' it's because the csv file has not completed downloading
     #' try increasing the time for Sys.sleep(time = x)
     #' ------- 
     #' delete the csv file
     file.remove(yahooCSV)
     # convert date as character to date format
     yahooDF$Date <- as.Date(yahooDF$Date)
     # convert to xts
     yahoo.xts    <- xts(yahooDF[,-1],order.by=yahooDF$Date)
     # assign the xts file to the specified environment
     # default is globalenv()
     assign(symbol, yahoo.xts, envir = as.environment(envir))
     print(symbol)
} #1
```

It works like this:

- Go to https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL
- Right click on "download data" and copy the link
- Copy the crumb after "&crumb=" and use it in the function call
- Set DLdir to the default download directory in your browser
  preferences
- Set envir = as.environment("yourEnvir") - defaults to globalenv()
- After downloading, the csv file is removed from your download
  directory to avoid clutter
- Note that this will leave an "untitled" window open in the browser
- As a simple test: getSymbols.yahoo.fix("AAPL")
  -

You can also use getSymbols.yahoo.fix with lapply to get a list of asset data

```
from       <- "2016-04-01"
to         <- Sys.Date()
period     <- "daily"
envir      <- globalenv()
crumb      <- "yourCrumb"
DLdir      <- "~/Downloads/"
assetList  <- c("AAPL", "ADBE", "AMAT")
lapply(assetList, getSymbols.yahoo.fix, from, to, envir = globalenv(), crumb = crumb, DLdir)}
```

Coded in RStudio on Mac OSX 10.11 using Safari as my default browser. It also appears to work with Chrome, but you will need to use the cookie crumb for Chrome. I use a cookie blocker but had to whitelist finance.yahoo.com to retain the cookie for future browser sessions.

getSymbols.yahoo.fix might be useful. qauantmod::getSymbols of necessity, has more code built in for options and exception-handling. I'm coding for personal work, so I often lift those pieces of code I need from package functions. I haven't benchmarked getSymbols.yahoo.fix because, of course, I don't have a working version of GetSymbol for comparison. Besides, I couldn't pass up the opportunity to enter my first stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

I too am encountering this error. A user on mrexcel fourm (jonathanwang003) explains that the new URL uses Unix Timecoding for dates. The updated VBA code would look something like this:

```
qurl = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" & Symbol
qurl = qurl & "?period1=" & (StartDate - DateSerial(1970, 1, 1)) * 86400 & _
       "&period2=" & (EndDate - DateSerial(1970, 1, 1)) * 86400 & _
       "&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=" & **Crumb**

QueryQuote:
With Sheets(Symbol).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets(Symbol).Range("a1"))
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
```

The missing piece here is how to retrieve the "Crumb" field that contains cookie information from the browser. Anyone have any ideas. I found this post, which may help: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1001259-when-using-querytables-what-posttext-syntax-click-button-webpage.html (look at last post by john_w).

Answer (score -1):

Try Google. The CSV is just a little different (does not have the adjusted price and the date has another format).

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:ADBE&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2009&enddate=Aug+2%2C+2012&output=csv

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=BVMF:PETR4&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2009&enddate=Aug+2%2C+2012&output=csv

Comment: It also accepts input dates in Unix timestamp format, and enddate is optional. You can parse the output dates with "new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH)"

Comment: The problem with google finance is that it sometimes doesn't recognize stock symbols. It sometimes requires us to know the cid, and even after that, it still doesn't download correctly sometimes...